# Intersection of tangent cones

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have no Idea how to solve this question:

> Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be convex and closed. Prove:
>
> $C \; is \; bounded \Leftrightarrow \cap_{x \in C} T(C,x)= \{0 \}$.

$T(C,x)$ ist the tagent cone of C in x and is defined by:

$T(C,x)=cl(\mathbb{R}_{+}(C-x))$ ,

where $cl(X)$ denotes the Closure of the set $X$.

Can you please give me an idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: I tried to solve this by the definitions, but I didn't come to any constructive result.

Comment: What you call here Tangent  cone is not really Tangent cone !

Answer (score 0):

Hint :   Show $$C \; is \; unbounded \Leftrightarrow \cap_{x \in C} T(C,x) \neq \{0 \}$$

$C$ is unbounded if and only if there is $d \neq 0 $ such that for all $x \in C $ and $\lambda \geq 0, \quad $  $x+ \lambda d \in C$

See [If points in a convex set $C$ escape to infinity roughly in direction $v$ then an infinite ray in that direction exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1408278/219176)

for proof